# Add event to tab selection in Lightswitch HTML client

Tags: lightswitch-2013

Using Lightwitch 2013 HTML client.
Am trying to add an event which will fire when a tab on a screen is selected (or clicked on).
I don't get any result with the following code :-

```
myapp.ViewThing.HistoryTab_postRender = function (element, contentItem) {
    $(element).click(function () { alert("clicked on tab !!!"); });
    $(element).select(function () { alert("selected tab !!!"); });
};
```

The above is the post render code for a tab on the screen.
The same kind of code works for other screen objects, eg text fields.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong, or why this shouldn't work for tabs ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

you can use jQuery to hook up a corresponding listener on the tab container (once per screen in any postRender event) and handle only the currently activated tab

```
myapp.ViewThing.HistoryTab_postRender = function (element, contentItem) {
    $(".msls-tabs-container li").on("click", function (e) {
        $.each(contentItem.screen.details.pages, function () {
            if (this.___isActivated) {
                // use 'this'
            };
        });
    });
};
```

another possibility is to search the DOM tree for the closest corresponding div using

```
myapp.ViewThing.HistoryTab_postRender = function (element, contentItem) {
    $(element).closest("div[data-role='page']").find(".msls-tabs-container li").click(function (e) {
        // use $(this)
    });
};
```

Comment: I used your first suggestion, but it seems that at the time of the click, the active tab is the tab that was active prior to the click. Anyway, using this at least I am able to call some code when any tab is clicked, and this is probably good enough for now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the created function

```
  $($.mobile.activePage
.find(".msls-screen-tab")[4]).on("click", function (e) {
    //Do something.
});
}, 0);
```

[4] is the tab order, starting with [0] for the first tab.

Regards
Sven